# Return data of file after it has been uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have referred to some Stack Overflow answers and managed to create an ASP.NET C# application that allows users to upload files (.txt). When I run the application, a page opens in the web browser, which shows “Choose file” and “Ok”. After I choose a file and enter “Ok”, the file is uploaded to an “uploads” folder in the project directory.

How do I edit my code to instead of the file just being uploading to the “uploads” folder, the data in the .txt file is displayed on the web browser page in JSON after I click “Ok” too?

I know that to read file the codes should be something like:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
return data;
```

However i am unsure on how to put these codes in to make the program work as required.

Here is what I have done so far:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the filename
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a bit awkward but you can do

```
<div>@ViewBag.JSON</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Then in your Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    if(TempData.ContainsKey("JSON") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)TempData["JSON"]))
    {
       ViewBag.JSON = System.IO.File.ReadAllText((string)TempData["JSON"]);
    }
        return View();
  }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the filename
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            TempData["JSON"] = path;
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Update** since you don't want to return any html back, change the code like so:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
        return View();
  }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the filename
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path));
            return null;
        }

        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for helping me. I get a red line under `TempData["JSON"]` error stating: `cannot convert from object to string`

Comment: I would like to ask one more question. This works but at the end of the data, i see "Choose file" and "Ok" buttons. I do not want that. What should i return instead?

Comment: Also, the data is not shown in JSON format it still has the <html> tags when i view it through 'view page source'. Is there any way to show it in complete json format?

Comment: It works just as i wanted it to ! Thank you so much ! :)